# In React 16.7, after setState call, getDerivedStateFromProps returning null is also updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After component gets rendered, I am calling updateResults method which is calling setState, after which getDerivedState is called and returning null, still state is getting updated and render and componentDidUpdate are called.

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), it shouldn't happen. Could anybody explain then why is it happening?

```
class Results extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {"query":props.data.web_query,"other_fields":props.other_fields};
  }  

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {

    if (state.query != props.data.web_query) {  
      console.log("Returning new state as expected");
      state.query = props.data.web_query;
      return state;
    }
    console.log("Returning null, shouldn't change state, but changing");

    return null;
 }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Componenent Did update");
  }

  updateResults(){
       let results = someAjaxCall(); 
       this.setState({"query":results.data.webquery,
                      "other_fields":results.other_fields});

  }

  render(){
      <SomeComponent updateCall={this.updateResults}/>
   }
}
```

Also, do explain how setState is related to getDerivedStateFromProps & shouldComponentUpdate?

Comment: please post a min. reproducible repo, so we can look

Comment: What does the state change to ?

Comment: Your render method will get called, regardless of state change ( i.e either returning the updated state object or null).

Comment: But if it is returning null, state should not get changed. It is changing state also.

Comment: What does that state change to ? 
null ?

Comment: No, some value changes. New data gets updated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't understand the purpose of getDerivedStateFromProps()

This method is used to update the state if the props change.

Even if the method is called after setState, if getDerivedStateFromProps return null the state will be updated with the data inside the setState but getDerivedStateFromProps can override some properties.

Comment: Ok. This sounds logical.